# Can meteor send notifications while in the background on android and iOS?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, meteor, meteor-cordova

Say a the app is running and a user gets a message (I suppose that would just be an change from the push/sub system) can meteor on iOS and android notify the app user even if all of this occurred while meteor was running in the background (not the open app or there is no open app) what about to the lock screen? Could it make a noise as well?

Answer (score 0):

Sure can, but you will need to use a Cordova library like this one https://github.com/raix/push